# What's Combinatorial Proof/Object/etc.?

Tags: combinatorics

In high school, when we talked about "combinatorics," we solely meant "mathematics of choice." For instance:

- There are 10 people who want to sit around a table. In how many ways is this possible?
- We have 50 balls and 20 boxes. In how many ways can we distribute balls into the boxes?
- There are 10 apples and 5 oranges. In how many ways can we select 7 fruits?
- ...

I did have this certain wrong view of combinatorics unless I read about combinatorial objects (lists, sets, graphs, etc.) and combinatorial proofs. I tried reading several sources (Wikipedia, books, papers), but still don't have a clear understanding of when something is called **combinatorial**.

> Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: Combinatorics is mathematics of counting.

Comment: And a *combinatorial proof* is a certain kind of proof which is especially favored in combinatorics. I think it's hard to improve on Wikipedia's explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_proof#The_benefit_of_a_combinatorial_proof

Comment: When I think about a combinatorial proof, I usually think about proof  by bijection or proof by double counting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several different branches of combinatorics but in general they deal with discrete structures.

*Enumerative combinatorics*, as the name suggests, deals with counting, so the combinatorics you learn in school mostly falls into this category, asking you for the number of permutations or combinations in a particular situation. *Extremal combinatorics*, for another example, asks for the largest or smallest structure satisfying certain properties. These terms are deliberately vague to allow for generality.

A *combinatorial proof* is simply a proof using a combinatorial argument. For example, one can prove the binomial theorem using mathematical induction or using a combinatorial argument, in which case what is to be justified is the coefficient of the various terms which is to be obtained by counting in some way.

Comment: I specially liked this answer for contrasting between **enumerative combinatorics** and **extremal combinatorics**, and pointing to the fact that "these terms are deliberately vague to allow for generality."

Answer (score 2):

A combinatorial argument often consists in giving a bijection between two sets or at least has such an observation as its key step. More precisely, one often starts with one set $A$ whose elements one wishes to count. You then find a bijection from $A$ to some other set $B$ whose elements are easily counted, leading to some expression for the number of elements of $A$.

A very simple example would be the problem of counting the number of subsets of some finite set of size $n$; call this set of subsets $A$. We first notice there's a bijection from $A$ to the set $B$ of length $n$ binary strings. We can easily count the number of elements of $B$; it's just $2^n$. Hence $A$ also has $2^n$ elements.

More generally, a combinatorial argument proceeds by noticing that some statement to be proved is equivalent to the assertion that two sets are in bijection and then by constructing an explicit bijection.